# worst case complexity improvement of Quick sort without converting it to mergsort

Tags: sorting, quicksort

Can the worst case time complexity of quick sort be changed from `O(n2)` to `O(nlogn)` by modifying it `(without converting it to mergsort)`?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, worst case is avoided by switching to heapsort if the number of recursions or partition splits becomes too large, since heapsort is also in place.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort

The other way to avoid worst case behavior is to use median of medians, although it's slower.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

As mentioned in the article, it can be a hybrid quicksort that switches to median of medians when the level of recursion becomes excessive.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect